# Interacting with actors in scala swing applications

Tags: swing, scala, actor

I'm writing a small application in scala. The application processes simple log files. Because the processing takes some time, I've decided to let my application core extend Actor.

```
class Application extends Actor {
  def react() {
    loop {
      react {
        case Process(file) => // do something interesting with file...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The processing of a log file is triggered by clicking a button in the gui. The gui uses scala swing.

```
object Gui extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  val application = new Application().start()

  def top = new MainFrame {
    val startButton = new Button

    reactions += {
      case ButtonClicked(`startButton`) => application ! Process(file)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the application core needs to notify the gui about the current progress.

```
  sender ! Progress(value) // whenever progress is made
```

I've solved this by creating a separate actor inside the gui. The actor is executed inside the edt thread. It listens to messages from the application core and updates the gui.

```
  object Gui extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    val actor = new Actor {
      override val scheduler = new SchedulerAdapter {
        def execute(fun: => Unit) { Swing.onEDT(fun) }
      }
      start()

      def act() {
        loop {
          react {
            case ForwardToApplication(message) => application ! message
            case Progress(value) => progressBar.value = value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Since the application core needs to know about the sender of the message, I also use this actor to forward messages from the gui to the application core, making my actor the new sender.

```
  reactions += {
    case ButtonClicked(`startButton`) => actor ! ForwardToApplication(Process(file))
  }
```

This code works just fine. My question: Is there a simpler way to do this? It whould be nice to simple use the reactions mechanism for my application messages:

```
  reactions += {
    case Progress(value) => progressBar.value = value
  }
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have extended on gerferras idea of making my application a `swing.Publisher`. The following class acts as intermediator between a `swing.Reactor` and an `Actor`.

```
import actors.Actor
import swing.Publisher
import swing.event.Event
import swing.Swing.onEDT

case class Send(event: Any)(implicit intermediator: Intermediator) {
  intermediator ! this
}
case class Receive(event: Any) extends Event

case class Intermediator(application: Actor) extends Actor with Publisher {
  start()

  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case Send(evt) => application ! evt
        case evt => onEDT(publish(Receive(evt)))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now my reactions can include both swing events and application events.

```
implicit val intermediator = Intermediator(application)
listenTo(intermediator, button)

reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(`button`) => Send(Process(file))
  case Receive(Progress(value)) => progressBar.value = value
}
```

Note how the `case class Send` provides some syntactic sugar to easily create events and pass them to the intermediator.

Comment: I think it's a good solution. Maybe I deserve an upvote in return ;)

Comment: I think you are missing `intermediator !` in your reaction to `ButtonClicked`

Comment: @geferra The `intermediator !` call is inside the constructor of `case class Send`. The `intermediator` is passed through an implicit parameter. I'm upvoting your answer since it provided inspiration for my own solution.

Comment: Hey, i just wanted to thank you for this solution. Looks like exactly what i have been looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is simpler but don't know if it's better. Instead of making your application backend an actor, you can create an anonymous actor every time you need to process the file:

```
reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(`startButton`) => application.process(file, { v: Int => Swing.onEDT(progressBar.value = v) })
}
```

For the progress update part, you can pass a callback to the process method to be executed every time a new progress is made:

```
import scala.actors.Actor.actor

def process(f: File, progress: Int => Unit) {
  actor {
    // process file while notifying the progress using the callback
    progress(n)
  }  
}
```

Alternatively (haven't tested) you could make your application a `scala.swing.Publisher` and, instead of using the callback, publish and event every time. So the code could be:

```
listenTo(startButton, application) //application is a Publisher

reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(`startButton`) => application.process(file)
  case Progress(v) => progressBar.value = v
}
```

And in the application:

```
import scala.actors.Actor.actor

def process(f: File) {
  actor {
    // process file while notifying the progress using an scala.swing.event.Event
    publish(Progess(n))
  }  
}
```

Comment: Your first idea with the callback works, but I think my approach with the actor is more extendable If I need to pass additional messages.

Comment: What about the second approach? Your application will be somewhat tied to a Swing front end but I think it's not that bad and, if I readed your question correctly, it's what you are asking for at the end

Comment: I've tried your second approach and somewhat extended it. See my own answer how this solution looks like.